# Should an OutputStream object (created as an expression in method call, but not assigned to a variable) still be closed?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to use a FileOutputStream anonymously for storing a property with java.util.Property's store method.

```
Properties p = new Properties();
. . .
p.store(new FileOutputStream("nameOfFile"), "Created by me.");
```

Reading the javadocs for the store method it says that the stream will be flushed and remain open after the method returns.

I'm wondering what happens with the stream. Since I've instantiated it anonymously I'm under the assumption that the object will be garbage collected immediately (if that is wrong, please correct me). However, I was taught to always close my streams when I'm finished with them. In this case, I am unable to close the stream since I have no object referring to it. Do I need to be worried about the stream being left open here, or does Java take care of it appropriately in this case by immediately collecting the object?

Comment: You have to be worried about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not an anonymous object (or rather an anonymous class). It's just an unassigned object instantiation.

Once you create it and pass it to `store` there is a reference to it, therefore it is not GC'd. Once `store` returns that reference disappears, but you should still track the variable and dispose of it after `store` returns. It is safer to just to treat all resources in the same standard way and call `close` when you are done with them, this helps avoid a lot of resource leak errors when some `finalize` methods call `close` ad other's don't, and also avoids issues due to non-deterministic GC.

You also *don't know what may change in a finalizer implementation in a future version* so always calling `close` is best practice.

A try-with-resources block ([Java Tutorials > The try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)) is ideal for this:

```
Properties p = new Properties();

try (FileOutputStream stm = new FileOutputStream("nameOfFile"))
{
    p.store(stm, "Created by me.");     
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO: handle this
}
```

That block, when used with any (and potentially multiple) `Autocloseable`, will call `close` at the end and nicely handle things like exceptions on `close` or exceptions in the body and on `close` as well. If both the body and `close` throw exceptions then the body exception is rethrown and the `close` exception is available through `e.getSuppressed()`.

You should not call [`Autocloseable.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html#method_summary) yourself if you use one of these blocks as that method is not indempotent - calling it twice may have side effects the second time. If you have a `Closeable` then you are safe to call it multiple times. From the docs:

> Note that unlike the close method of Closeable, this close method is not required to be idempotent

In Java 6 or less you have to do your own exception handling statement which is hard as you have to handle the case where both your body, and the `close` both throw exceptions.

Comment: @user2864740. True, I was fast and loose with that term. I mean you have an unassigned instantiated object - there is only an implicit variable through the method argument. I have been more precise in my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Garbage collection generally does not include resources like open files or streams, unless the `finalize` method explicitly closes the underlying resources of the object.

Checking the code of `finalize` for `FileOutputStream`, it seems to make sure the `close` is called:

```
/**
 * Cleans up the connection to the file, and ensures that the
 * <code>close</code> method of this file output stream is
 * called when there are no more references to this stream.
 *
 * @exception  IOException  if an I/O error occurs.
 * @see        java.io.FileInputStream#close()
 */
protected void finalize() throws IOException {
    if (fd != null) {
        if (fd == FileDescriptor.out || fd == FileDescriptor.err) {
            flush();
        } else {

            /*
             * Finalizer should not release the FileDescriptor if another
             * stream is still using it. If the user directly invokes
             * close() then the FileDescriptor is also released.
             */
            runningFinalize.set(Boolean.TRUE);
            try {
                close();
            } finally {
                runningFinalize.set(Boolean.FALSE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, it's always better to *always* close the resource manually, or in a `try-with-resources` statement, because not all stream objects may close upon being de-referenced, and even if they do finalization is not guaranteed to occur according to expectations:

```
try(FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("nameOfFile")) {
     Properties p = new Properties();
     . . .
     p.store(outStream, "Created by me.");
}
```

Comment: Note: finalizers should not be 'relied' upon to release external resources. When (and if) the finalizer does run it will release the system resource, but not prior .. a safety net is better than nothing; but it still means you fell (first mistake) and the net might break (bad luck).

Comment: Also, it's better not to leave this for the finalizer because although the object will become eligible for garbage collection, you never know when and if finalization will happen before the program terminates. It may wait a long time in the finalizer queue and if there are many such objects, resources may run out.

Comment: @manouti. My biggest issue with relying on `finalize` for `close` is that the implementation may remove calls to `close` in future versions without you realising, and then you will have resource leaks.

Comment: @AndyBrown My goal of including the `finalize` method was not to rely on it but to illustrate that effectively when a `FileOutputStream` _does_ get finalized, its `close` method is invoked. It's definitely a risk that one should avoid though.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object...

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("nameOfFile")
```

And then use it...

```
p.store(fos, "Created by me.");
```

Close it on finally.

The Properties.store() command does not keep a reference to the stream hence there are no references to it and hence it will be GC'ed after the method returns as that is the extent of the streams scope.

Comment: That's not the way to do it, Aninda - you have to worry about exception handling now. Just use a "try with resources" block.

Comment: You are presuming the JDK version as 7 and I have not given a full code just a hint. I agree it will complain about a catch, which we should give in lower versions @AndyBrown.

Comment: You shouldn't actually be using lower versions. JDK 6 is no longer supported.

Comment: Sorry @RealSkeptic, but it depends. There are enterprise solutions still using < 6 for their own reasons. And I believe this is not a point of discussion. Thanks for the input, though.